# How do you say something equivalent to French expression "public facile"?

Tags: expressions, translation, french

In French, there is an expression that says "public facile" ... means somebody who will easily approve/enjoy pieces music or other arts if they are asked their opinion.

I would tend to translate it to "easy audience" , but does it actually have the same meaning in English and if not, what is the English way of saying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might say "a receptive audience", though that may refer to a momentary rather than a persistent condition. Maybe "an easy-to-please audience" or "an audience easy to please", or "an uncritical audience".

Comment: "an easy-to-please audience" is the most easily understood

Comment: A receptive audience can often be an audience predisposed to agree with an opinion or proposition.

Comment: Thank you. I feel like I might use "an easy-to-please/uncritical audience".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Right, like those gathered for a political rally.